# how to calculate 1000 digit number divided by 13

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

*N = 111...111* which consists of 1000 digits of ones. 
What is the remainder of N upon division by 13?

*N = 111...111=111...08+3*

N = 4k+3 but I can not go further.

Comment: Hint: $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$.

Comment: So $n=\frac19(10^{1000}-1)$.

Comment: $1001*111=111,111$.  $1000 = 6*166+4$. So $1111....1=111,111*10,000,010,000,010.....010,000 + 1111$.  The remainder of $1001$ is $0$.  So the remainder of $111,111$ is zero.  So there remainder of $11,11,111,111,1111,....,110,000$ is $0$.  so the remainder if $11,11,111,111,1111,....,111$ is the same as the remainder of $1111=1001+110$ which is the same as the remainder of $110$ which is the same as $136$ or $6$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your number $N=11 \ldots 1$, with $1000$ digits, is equal to $(10^{1000}-1)/9$, and since gcd$(10,13)=1$, we have by Fermat's little theorem that $10^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow (10^{12})^{83} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ and so $10^{1000} = 10^{12\times 83 +4} \equiv 10^4 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$, then, finally, $10^{1000}-1\equiv 2 \pmod{13}$, which gives us that $9N \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$. Multiplying both sides by $3$, we get  $N \equiv 3\times9 N \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$. So, $N \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$.

Comment: $10^4equiv3\pmod{13}$

Comment: Better check work - I get  $6$ after checking my work.

Answer (score 1):

$1001$ is divisible by $13$,

$111,111$ is divisible by $1001.$

if you have a number that is all 1's and the number of 1's is divisibe by 6, then the number will be divisible by 111111, 1001 and 13.

Answer (score 0):

Using Doug M's hint and the fact that $1000 \pmod{6} \equiv 4$ we know that

$\tag 1 N \equiv 1111 \pmod{13}$

subtracting $1001$ we can write

$\tag 2 N \equiv 110 \pmod{13}$

ANS: $N \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$